# SELECT Statement with NULL and Non-Null Values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure, and It should be able to accept null values (tmpParameter) as well as non-null values (smallint). How would I combine the logic so that it can handle both of them in one select statement?

```
IF @tmpParameter IS NULL
SELECT [Key]
      ,[Parent_Key]
      ,[Parent_Code]
      ,[Code]
      ,[Desc] 
      ,[Point]
      ,[By] 
      ,[On]
FROM [db].[stats] t WHERE t.[Parent_Key] IS NULL
ELSE
SELECT [Key]
      ,[Parent_Key]
      ,[Parent_Code]
      ,[Code]
      ,[Desc] 
      ,[Point]
      ,[By] 
      ,[On]
FROM [db].[stats] t WHERE t.[Parent_Key]= @tmpParameter
```

Is there any way I can do that in one statement?

Comment: Can `t.[Parent_Key]` ever be negative?

Comment: @SIYUAL nah, it is a primary key, generated by sql

Comment: Since it is not going to be negative just give your parameter a default value of -1. Then you only need a single query and your where clause would be where t.Parent_Key = @ tmpParameter OR @ tmpParameter = -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to write for the reader. So I would just go with what is clear. (And index friendly.)

```
SELECT  [Key]
        ,[Parent_Key]
        ,[Parent_Code]
        ,[Code]
        ,[Desc] 
        ,[Point]
        ,[By] 
        ,[On]
FROM    [db].[stats] t 
WHERE   t.[Parent_Key] = @tmpParameter 
OR (t.[Parent_Key] IS NULL AND  @tmpParameter IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `t.[Parent_Key]` cannot be negative, you can use `Coalesce` to force `Null` to be -1, and check that in one statement:

```
SELECT  [Key]
        ,[Parent_Key]
        ,[Parent_Code]
        ,[Code]
        ,[Desc] 
        ,[Point]
        ,[By] 
        ,[On]
FROM    [db].[stats] t 
WHERE   COALESCE(t.[Parent_Key], -1) = COALESCE(@tmpParameter, -1)
```

If `@tmpParameter` is null, it would return any `Parent_Key` that is Null, by casting both as -1.  If it isn't null, it will return any `Parent_Key` that was that value.

Comment: This query is nonSARGable and will not perform well on large datasets.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not sure what you mean by nonSARGable?

Comment: sargable = "search argumentable". In other words when your wrap your columns in a function in a join or a where clause predicate your query will not be able to use any index on that column. It will force a scan instead of a seek.

Comment: There are tons of references out there but there is the wiki page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: @SeanLange Interesting, I wasn't aware of that.  Would selecting the `Coalesce` values in an inner-select and comparing those values allow it to use the indexes?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean but I suspect that once you start adding subselects you are going the wrong direction performance wise.

Comment: Most definitely, though I was mostly trying to wrap my head around the sargable concept.

Comment: When dealing with indexes think about a phone book. Take me to the page that begins with "Lan". This is pretty simple because you can skip to about the middle or so right? However if I said give me all the names that contain "Lan" you would have to look at every single name in the phone book. This concept is the same with indexes. Once you wrap your column in a function the engine has to evaluate the result of the function for every single row. Does that help?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, that helps a lot!  Thanks for taking the time to explain it.